# Entity Framework - GroupBy then OrderBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a group of records that includes PatientID and Appointment Date.

I would like to group them by PatientID and order the groups by the oldest appointment in each PatientID group. Like this...

```
 ID     ApptDate
----------------------
  3    2/5/2005   (oldest compared to all groups , so group "ID = 3" is sorted first)
  3    5/10/2006
  3    6/2/2010

  1    8/5/2007
  1    9/1/2015 

  2    6/15/2009
  2    9/19/2009
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use grouping first to obtain the oldest date value for each ID and then order by that value but I am stuck understanding how the two functions will work together.

```
var query = from a in db.Appointments
group a by new { a.Id, a.ApptDate} into pa
select new { 
     ID = pa.Key.Id,  
     Date = pa.Min(x =>x.ApptDate) ...
```

... but I crash and burn at this point.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to order first and then group

Comment: From the docs of GroupBy *The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.*

Comment: why do you group by ApptDate also? Why not simply only group by Id and then order the groups by value.Select(x=>x.Min(y=>y.ApptDate))?

Comment: It should be Min() call since your question says sorting oldest records first.

Comment: Tanveer - you are correct. I changed my example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified a bit Tanveer Badar's answer to return a row for each entity.

Create a class for your return data

```
public class ReturnType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppDate { get; set; }
}
```

Get a group of IDs and enumerable of ordered dates

```
var result = db.Appointment
            .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
            .OrderBy(a => a.Min(n => n.Date))
            .Select(a => new { ID = a.Key, AppDates = a.OrderBy(na => 
na.Date).Select(ne => ne.Date) })
            .ToList();
```

Then flatten the returned list. I tried with SelectMany but with no success.

```
var results = new List<ReturnType>();
        foreach (var a in result)
        {
            foreach (var date in a.AppDates)
            {
                var returnType = new ReturnType
                {
                    ID = a.ID,
                    AppDate = date
                };

                results.Add(returnType);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This returns a list ordered on PatientID

Comment: @RPollack Are you sure? I tested it exactly with the example you provided and it returned the right values.

Comment: Right, not using core. Let me try running it again

Comment: @RPollack I thought that because in EF Core (prior to 2.1) GroupBy translates to OrderBy and then it shall return you values ordered by PatientID. But since you use EF. GroupBy works correctly, and if you check the code, there is no ordering by PatientID so what you got looks bizarre to me.

Comment: M Bakardzhiev - I tried again and not only is it ordering by PatientID but the ApptDate within each PatientID group is not ordered at all. I am trying your solution  with production data different than the example data in my OP.

Comment: I'm using EF6.2

Comment: @RPollack Check my new answer, I tested it with real data from a database.

Comment: YES. Your revised answer works! I just needed to add "()" at the end of the "var returnType = new ReturnType" line. Thank you!

Comment: @RPollack Glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You requirements are as follows (though the question does not mention one of them, but it is apparent from how data is laid out):

1. Group based on patient ID.
2. Sort groups based on oldest appointment date in each group.
3. Sort data within a group based on appointment date.

`var query = records.GroupBy(r => r.PatientId) // Group patients
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Min(r => r.AppointmentDate)) // sort groups by oldest record in each
                    .Select(g => 
                       new 
                       {
                            PatientId = g.Key, 
                            Records = g.OrderBy(r => r.AppointmentDate) // sort records within a group by oldest
                       });`

Comment: Yes you are correct regarding the requirement 3, however your code seems to return only a single row per patient (group) instead of all rows of each patient.

Comment: You would need to run nested loops to iterate over all the data. Did you even try visualizing query results in a debugger?

Answer (score -1):

In my case it works fine...

```
var query = from a in db.Appointments
    group a by new { a.Id, a.ApptDate} into pa
    select new { 
         ID = pa.Key.Id,  
         Date = pa.Max(x =>x.ApptDate)
       }).Select(x=>new { 
                             x.ID,x.Date
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: It should be pa.Min() since oldest records appear first, secondly there's no OrderBy() in your answer.

Comment: This returns a  list  ordered by patientID instead of ordering by the earliest appointment date in each patientId group.

Comment: As suggested I added OrderBy(y => y.Date) before the .Select and it does order properly but it is only returning one row per PatientID. How can I get the other PatientID rows to display?

Answer (score -1):

```
db.Appointments.GroupBy(new {ID = item.ID, ApptDate = item.ApptDate}).OrderByDescending(item => item.ApptDate)
```

Comment: This won't even compile, because the IGrouping does not have a property "ApptDate".